# MLKit face detection 's algorithm

Tags: face-detection, google-mlkit

MLKit provides good API documentations and guides for Face detection (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection). However, I can not find any informations about the algorihms/baseline model or related research papers behind the scene. Can someone provide any suggestions about it's implementation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It likely uses `blazeface` for face detection used on mediapipe. I could not find a direct answer, but when analyzing an apk with mlkit face detection `blazeface.tfl` can be found on assets folder.

[image]

Mediapipe pose detection [doc mentions](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose.html) `blazepose` powers the ML Kit Pose Detection API. So, blazeface is likely to power mlkit on device face detection.

Links to documentation, paper, poster,

https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_detection.html

https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05047

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1YCtASfnYyZtH-41QvnW5iZxELFnf0MF-pPWSLGj8yjQ/present?slide=id.g5bc8aeffdd_1_0

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u6aB6wxDY7X2TmeUUKgFydulNtXkb3pu/view

Answer (score 0):

I found ml kit facedetection sdk version has not been update for a long time， and the face mesh sdk is not reliable， maybe mediapipe is the best choice

Answer (score -1):

ML Kit's selection of APIs run on-device or in the cloud. The on-device APIs can  work when there's no network connection. The cloud-based APIs is built on top of TensorFlow Lite along with the integrated Neural Network API. So we do not need to integrate AI-based algorithms into mobile apps. I found the explanation on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_detection#:%7E:text=Face%2Ddetection%20algorithms%20focus%20on,will%20invalidate%20the%20matching%20process.):

> Face detection can be regarded as a specific case of object-class detection. Face-detection algorithms focus on the detection of frontal human
> faces.
>
> A reliable face-detection approach based on the genetic algorithm and
> the eigen-face technique.

There are other face recognition algorithms, like Principal Component Analysis(PCA) and Linear Discriminate Analysis (LDA) algorithms.

Comment: Small correction, ML Kit's on-device APIs do not use Cloud Vision API, they fully run on the device locally. Another source for the technology behind the API is the MediaPipe website (https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_detection)